# Dynamically populating a drop down list with functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a chess puzzle app in javascript. I want to make a feature so a user can select a puzzle from a drop down menu. Using a library called Chess JS, a chess position is loaded using this function:

```
game = new Chess("FEN string");
```

I have an array of FEN strings like this:

```
var puzzleArray =['6R1/5q1p/3Qp1pk/p3Pp2/Ppr2P2/2P4P/6PK/8 w - - 0 1','rnbqkbnr/ppp1p1pp/8/3p1p2/4P3/2P5/PP1P1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 3'];
```

I am generating a drop down menu like this:

```
<html>

     <select id="selectPuzzle">

      </select>

</html>
<script>
    var select = document.getElementById("selectPuzzle"); 
    var options = ["Kasparov-Mamedyarov", "Beliavsky-Timman"];

    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }​

</script>
```

I want to make it so that when an option is selected, a function is run to load a new game from the puzzleArray, so when you select "Kasparov-Mamedyarov" from the drop down, the following code will be run:

```
game = new Chess("puzzleArray[0]");
```

Any help would be great cheers!

Comment: Just add: `el.onchange = function(){ var game = new Chess("puzzleArray[0]"); }` before you append it into the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectPuzzle"); 
var options = ["Kasparov-Mamedyarov", "Beliavsky-Timman"];

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}

select.onchange = function(){
  console.log(this.value);
  //game = new Chess(this.value);
}
```

```html
  <select id="selectPuzzle"></select>
```

You also might want to add a "blank" start value (empty option), or also run the handler on page load, because onchange doesnt fire until you change the option. (you won't be able to select the "preselected" value, unless you change it to something else first)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

     <select id="selectPuzzle" onchange='usePlayer()'>

      </select>

</html>
<script>
  function usePlayer()
  {
    var select = document.getElementById("selectPuzzle"); 
    game = new Chess(select.value);
  }
    var select = document.getElementById("selectPuzzle"); 
    var options = ["Kasparov-Mamedyarov", "Beliavsky-Timman"];

    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.innerHTML = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }

</script>
```

Try this. Set the inner html intsead of text :D
I haven't really seen the text property in use. But generally I set thge innerHTML. Hope that helps. Comment if there's more issues aside form that one.

Don't know what the Chess class looks like, but I defined one in code pen and selected new options several times.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Gotcha, Added the part to actually use the selects name. Add an onChange event and point it to a funciton you define in your script.

Comment: This still doesn't address the question. The OP wants `game = new Chess(select.value);` to happen when the `select` has its option changed.

Comment: It does, if you look at the select option, it fires an function that initiates a new Chess. Read the code before down voting.

Comment: usePlayer is defined in the script. when the select element is changed, the function fires, which takes the current select value and assigns game to a new instance of chess using said value